# SSL Handshake failed with Android 7.0 supporting secp256r1 curve

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, openssl

We started encountering SSL Handshake error on a few old mobile devices after upgrading our web-server from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. 
On digging a bit deeper we noticed a few things

1. The mobile devices which were facing this issue had Android 7.0 as their operating system.
2. On upgrading the Android operating system, SSL handshake happened smoothly.
3. The error we got on the mobile during handshake was

   > SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x8c78e100: Failure in SSL library,
   >   usually a protocol error error:10000410:SSL
   >   routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
   >   (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0x7a7c16e0:0x00000001)
   >   error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIE
4. The error we saw on enabling debug error log on openresty web-server was

   > SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417A0C1:SSL
   >   routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher) while SSL
   >   handshaking,
5. The ecdh curves listed in web-server configuration were secp384r1:prime256v1:secp521r1
6. The only ecdh curve supported by the Android device as seen in Wireshark during client helo was secp256r1.
7. As far as we understood prime256v1 and secp256r1 are both NIST P-256 , so since we support prime256v1 and android device supports secp256r1, this should work, but doesn't.
8. On trying to specify secp256r1 in web-server, it fails with following error.

   > [emerge] SSL_CTX_set1_curves_list("secp384r1:prime256v1:secp521r1:secp256r1")
   >   failed (SSL:)
9. Another thing to note is that we support TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 in our web-server
10. Below is the list of curves supported by the openssl

    > root@staging-senpiper:/etc/openresty# openssl ecparam -list_curves
    >   secp112r1 : SECG/WTLS curve over a 112 bit prime field
    >   secp112r2 : SECG curve over a 112 bit prime field
    >   secp128r1 : SECG curve over a 128 bit prime field
    >   secp128r2 : SECG curve over a 128 bit prime field
    >   secp160k1 : SECG curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   secp160r1 : SECG curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   secp160r2 : SECG/WTLS curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   secp192k1 : SECG curve over a 192 bit prime field
    >   secp224k1 : SECG curve over a 224 bit prime field
    >   secp224r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 224 bit prime field
    >   secp256k1 : SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
    >   secp384r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 384 bit prime field
    >   secp521r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 521 bit prime field
    >   prime192v1: NIST/X9.62/SECG curve over a 192 bit prime field
    >   prime192v2: X9.62 curve over a 192 bit prime field
    >   prime192v3: X9.62 curve over a 192 bit prime field
    >   prime239v1: X9.62 curve over a 239 bit prime field
    >   prime239v2: X9.62 curve over a 239 bit prime field
    >   prime239v3: X9.62 curve over a 239 bit prime field
    >   prime256v1: X9.62/SECG curve over a 256 bit prime field
    >   sect113r1 : SECG curve over a 113 bit binary field
    >   sect113r2 : SECG curve over a 113 bit binary field
    >   sect131r1 : SECG/WTLS curve over a 131 bit binary field
    >   sect131r2 : SECG curve over a 131 bit binary field
    >   sect163k1 : NIST/SECG/WTLS curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   sect163r1 : SECG curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   sect163r2 : NIST/SECG curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   sect193r1 : SECG curve over a 193 bit binary field
    >   sect193r2 : SECG curve over a 193 bit binary field
    >   sect233k1 : NIST/SECG/WTLS curve over a 233 bit binary field
    >   sect233r1 : NIST/SECG/WTLS curve over a 233 bit binary field
    >   sect239k1 : SECG curve over a 239 bit binary field
    >   sect283k1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 283 bit binary field
    >   sect283r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 283 bit binary field
    >   sect409k1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 409 bit binary field
    >   sect409r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 409 bit binary field
    >   sect571k1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 571 bit binary field 
    >   sect571r1 : NIST/SECG curve over a 571 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb163v1: X9.62 curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb163v2: X9.62 curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb163v3: X9.62 curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb176v1: X9.62 curve over a 176 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb191v1: X9.62 curve over a 191 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb191v2: X9.62 curve over a 191 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb191v3: X9.62 curve over a 191 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb208w1: X9.62 curve over a 208 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb239v1: X9.62 curve over a 239 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb239v2: X9.62 curve over a 239 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb239v3: X9.62 curve over a 239 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb272w1: X9.62 curve over a 272 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb304w1: X9.62 curve over a 304 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb359v1: X9.62 curve over a 359 bit binary field
    >   c2pnb368w1: X9.62 curve over a 368 bit binary field
    >   c2tnb431r1: X9.62 curve over a 431 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls1: WTLS curve over a 113 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls3: NIST/SECG/WTLS curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls4: SECG curve over a 113 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls5: X9.62 curve over a 163 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls6: SECG/WTLS curve over a 112 bit prime field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls7: SECG/WTLS curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls8: WTLS curve over a 112 bit prime field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls9: WTLS curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls10: NIST/SECG/WTLS curve over a 233 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls11: NIST/SECG/WTLS curve over a 233 bit binary field
    >   wap-wsg-idm-ecid-wtls12: WTLS curve over a 224 bit prime field
    >   Oakley-EC2N-3:    IPSec/IKE/Oakley curve #3 over a 155 bit binary field.  Not suitable for ECDSA.     Questionable extension field!
    >   Oakley-EC2N-4:    IPSec/IKE/Oakley curve #4 over a 185 bit binary field.  Not suitable for ECDSA.     Questionable extension field! 
    >   brainpoolP160r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP160t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 160 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP192r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 192 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP192t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 192 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP224r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 224 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP224t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 224 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP256r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 256 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP256t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 256 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP320r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 320 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP320t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 320 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP384r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 384 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP384t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 384 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP512r1: RFC 5639 curve over a 512 bit prime field
    >   brainpoolP512t1: RFC 5639 curve over a 512 bit prime field   SM2
    >   : SM2 curve over a 256 bit prime field

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Same problem with Android 10 builtin mail client vs. sslserver (qmail) ucspi on port 465 (SSL accept every certs). Dovecot offering secp256r1 and it's ok. But ucspi-ssl offering secp521r1 and doesn't work/hanshake